# can't install/run jenkins on ubuntu ec2

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I have a ubuntu ec2 which I am trying to install and run Jenkins on, but it won't load up the Jenkins admin, keeps getting

> This site can’t be reached. 3.86.201.232 refused to connect.

but when I check the status of Jenkins, it's active (Please see attached image)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jcMX.png

Note, when I tried to curl http://localhost, it also failed to connect, but I have my http and https port 80 open already from my security group, help!

Answer (score 1):

By default Jenkins runs on port `8080`. Have you changed the default port? Try accessing `http://3.86.201.232:8080/login?from=%2F`

This seems to be accessible :p

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Figured it out a few minutes after I posted the question, I added the port number then it loaded. But, another newbie question, I thought omitting the port number is the same as 8080, I guess not? Thanks @ycr!

Comment: @Hank Nope it's not! If you omit the port, for HTTP calls by default port 80 will be picked and for HTTPS the port 443 will be picked up.  If you want to access Jenkins through port 80 you need to either start it on port 80 or deploy a reverse proxy to reroute traffic from 80 to 8080.  Latter is the most common deployment pattern.